# PDOException SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found

Tags: php, idiorm

> Type: PDOException
>
> Code: 42S22
>
> Message: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Champ 'id' inconnu dans where clause
>   File: C:\wamp\www\viversoft\vendor\j4mie\idiorm\idiorm.php
>   Line: 413

### My code is:

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
    {% if is_admin %} 
        <a href="{{urlFor('altausers')}}" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Crear usuario</a>
    {% endif %}
    <h2>Listado de usuarios</h2>
    {% if users %}
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Nombre de usuario</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Administrador</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for user in users %}
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">{{ user.idusuario }}</td>
                <td class="text-center">{{ user.username }}</td>
                <td class="text-center">{{ user.email }}</td>
                <td class="text-center">{%if user.admin == 1 %} SI {%else%} NO {% endif %}</td>
                {% if is_admin %}
                    <td>
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Modificar</a>
                        <button type='submit' name="eliminar" id="eliminar" value="{{user['idusuario']}}" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteconfirm(this.value);">Eliminar</button>
                    </td>
                {% endif %}
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}   
        </tbody>
    </table>
  {% else %}
      <div class="alert alert-info">No hay usuarios para mostrar</div>
  {% endif %}
  </form>
```

---

### routes

```
$app->post('/users', function() use($app){if(isset($_POST['eliminar'])){
        $user = ORM::for_table('usuario')->find_one($_POST['eliminar']);
        if($user)
        {
            $user->delete();
            $app->redirect($app->urlFor('userList'));
        }
   }})->name("userDelete");
```

---

### phpmyadmin

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuario` (
       `idusuario` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
       `contrasenia` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
       `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
       `admin` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
        PRIMARY KEY (`idusuario`)) 
        ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Did you read the error: Column not found: 1054 Champ 'id'. Do you have a column named 'id' or is it 'idusuario'?

Comment: Check if `ORM::for_table('usuario')->where('idusuario', $_POST['eliminar'])->find_one();` works.

Comment: I try it and dont work

Comment: Can you check on phpmyadmin that your database contains that table and that table has that column?

Comment: I've tried to replicate your issue for the `users` route but it works for me. Try to delete the database and recreate it using your installation script.

Comment: I solved the problem by default it´s in find_one(id) and I´ve change in my database the name´s column. I haved idusuario and changed to id.

Answer (score 2):

I think here you have the issue and I am not sure

//$user = ORM::for_table('usuario')->find_one($_POST['eliminar']);

Change the above line as follows and try

```
$user = ORM::for_table('usuario')->find_one(array('idusuario' => $_POST['eliminar']));
```

Comment: It don´t work  Type: PDOException
Code: HY093
Message: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined
File: C:\wamp\www\viversoft\vendor\j4mie\idiorm\idiorm.php
Line: 413

Comment: I tried it  $user = ORM::for_table('usuario')->find_one(array('idusuario' => $_POST['delete'])); and get the error Type: PDOException
Code: HY093
Message: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined
File: C:\wamp\www\viversoft\vendor\j4mie\idiorm\idiorm.php
Line: 413